# iPhone to Max with OSC: certain int messages get zero'd

Tags: iphone, osc

I'm using the berkely OSC library.

I'm using OSC_writeAddress() followed by OSC_writeIntArg() to send OSC buffers from iPhone to max/msp, one packet at a time. my range of values goes from 0 - 320. this works for integers 0 - 53, 74 - 127, 197 - 309 inclusive but all other values that i try to send arrive at max as 0.000000. I'm using the udpreceive object and the opensoundcontrol max external within max

i can't seem to get float args decoded properly at all on the max side and using writeAddressAndTypes doesn't work either.

Does anybody know where these 0's are coming from??

Thanks.

here's the general idea in code:

```
int addressResult = OSC_writeAddress(&myOSCBuff, (char*)oscAddress);

int writeRestult = OSC_writeIntArg(&myOSCBuff, sendVal);

CFSocketError sendError = CFSocketSendData(udpSocket, connectAddr, OSCPacketWithAddressTest, 30);
```